# Unique Elements in a Vector of tuples with inner tuples

Tags: scala, distinct

I am having a Vector containing Tuples like:

```
Vector( (a1,(a2,(a3,a4))),(b1,(b2,(b3,b4))),(c1,(c2,(c3,c4))),...............)
```

This vector is very long and I got repeated (equal) values for a1,b1,c1....etc and also for a2,b2,c2...etc..and similarly for a3,b3,c3,....etc.
My requirement is:

I want three vectors with unique elements of a1,b1.c1....etc,and  of a2,b2,c2....etc, and of a3,b3,c3....etc (ie.,distinct based on `first appearance` of that particular element.)

Is there a way to do that in Scala with concise code assuming 
that all these values are integers or doubles?

Example:

GIVEN Vector :

```
Vector( (2,(8,(4,5))),(6,(3,(7,9))),(2,(3,(7,9))),(2,(8,(4,5))))
```

ANSWERS:

```
Vector1 : Vector( (2,(8,(4,5))),(6,(3,(7,9))) ) 
Vector2 : Vector( (2,(8,(4,5))),(6,(3,(7,9))) )
Vector3 : Vector( (2,(8,(4,5))),(6,(3,(7,9))) )
```

ie.,distinct based on `first appearance` of that particular element.

Comment: Hope the above example may explain what is the requirement.

Comment: how do you choose one tuple over another when there's a duplicate?

Comment: Is the order of the result `Vector` meaningful or is it sufficient as long as it has all the correct elements?

Comment: I got this type of tuple vector as part of some computations. It is meaningful. And I needed to check the three types of results based on unique elements.

Comment: Your 3 answers are all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupBy`, then just get the first result from each group:

```
 val vec = Vector((2, (8, (4, 5))),
                  (6, (3, (7, 9))),
                  (2, (3, (7, 9))),
                  (2, (8, (4, 5))))
 val vector1 = vec.groupBy(_._1).values.map(_.head)
 val vector2 = vec.groupBy(_._2._1).values.map(_.head)
 val vector3 = vec.groupBy(_._2._2._1).values.map(_.head)
```

This breaks ties by first element, as requested. Note, however, that there are no guarantees about the order of the elements in vector1, vector2, and vector3.